# Silently Opening HTTP Connections in Java?

Tags: java, http

How would I go about silently opening up a HTTP connection to a certain website in Java?
I tried `.openConnection()` and it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by silently?

Comment: As in it doesn't open in a web browser and does it within the program.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work".

Comment: Well, my PHP script that the Java program was supposed to connect to didn't show any results (when I tried it from the web browser it worked perfectly fine) (the script would log the connection).

Comment: Show us some code. Show us an exception backtrace. Otherwise, this is very likely to be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find out why `.openConnection()` isn't working.  Catch the exception thrown by that call and print out the exception's full stacktrace.  That should give you the information you need to start diagnosing.

The javadoc for [`URL.openConnection()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29) says this:

> *"It should be noted that a `URLConnection` instance does not establish the actual network connection on creation. This will happen only when calling `URLConnection.connect()`."*

That call can occur explicitly or implicitly; i.e. when you attempt to read the response status, headers or body.  Read the javadocs for URLConnection and HttpURLConnection for more details.

So it sounds like `openConnection` *is* working ... but it doesn't do what you expect it to.

Comment: But what if they're running the Java code outside of a web browser?

Comment: Yeah, I'm asking how to establish the connection from a Java program running from the command line.

Comment: Is .openConnection() supposed to open an active HTTP connection? Because I got no compiling errors or anything but when the program ran, nothing happened.